# Scrape a page after it is finished loading/redirected

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, cheerio

Page in question:

```
http://watch2gether.com/go#<link>
```

I need to be able to scrape this page after it has loaded completely and redirected to its final destination.

Now, to elaborate on my question:
I have been using request and cheerio to try to scrape the page, and I have successfuly with this:

```
var searchTerm = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=link';
var url = 'https://www.watch2gether.com/go#' + searchTerm;

request(url, function(err, resp, body){
  $ = cheerio.load(body);
  links = $('link'); //use your CSS selector here
  $(links).each(function(i, link){
    sleep.sleep(2);
    console.log($(link).text() + ':\n  ' + $(link).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

However, it returns the values of each href attribute BEFORE the page has actually loaded and redirected to the final page, so it is really scraping http://watch2gether.com/go# instead of http://watch2gether.com/rooms/

since the second page is only loaded after the first is requested, how could I make my code scrape the second page instead of the first one?

Answer (score 0):

> since the second page is only loaded after the first is requested, how could I make my code scrape the second page instead of the first one?

I did not entirely understand this segment of your question. However, i think what you are experiencing is the asynchronous nature of javascript.

When you do

> $(links).each(function(i, link){
>   // your additional code here
>   })

the async nature of javascript fetches all the links according to your CSS selector on $('links'). After it has loaded all the links it starts executing the rest of your code and redirects/does things accordingly.

Please check event loop or asynch nature of javascript.